# What did Commodore's AppShell and AppObject do?

Tags: amiga

Among the many developed but never released software that Commodore developed for the Amiga there should be two applications, called AppShell and AppObject. What were these? Did anyone ever saw or used them?

Answer (score 5):

From AppShell's author, David N. Junod in [comp.sys.amiga.programmer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.amiga.programmer/3yiSXQKIc7I/s9mGpsDwU1IJ):

> AppShell was the next generation after ModEngine.  ModEngine was an
>   AmigaMail article that I wrote about modular event programming, and thought
>   was put on a Fish Disk (although I can't locate it right now).
>
> ModEngine was next generation to work I had done before going to C= (I don't
>   think I ever heard of anything called "VIC").
>
> Basically, AppShell provide a user-interface independant method of writing
>   applications.  You would write the functions of your application according
>   to the AppShell way and you would "magically" get an ARexx interface, CLI
>   interface (like TxEd) and GUI.  AppShell would also give you most of the
>   functionality of the Amiga User Interface Style Guide without you having to
>   write the code.  There was also a companion appobjects.library that
>   contained a number of neato GUI objects (multi-column listview, image
>   buttons, etc.)
>
> AppShell was given away on the DevCon disks---so if you have them, you have
>   AppShell.  It never reached a release state, because when I moved from CATS
>   to Engineering, it was basically dropped.